# c++ game engine design and objects going out of scope

Tags: c++, scope, game-engine

I'm working on a small component based game engine in C++. Various components are added to an internal list of a gameobject object, to save some time I don't make a member variable of these components, only the game object is a member variable, like so:

```
void Initialize()
{     
   MeshComponent* meshRenderer = new MeshComponent(mesh, material);
   m_GameObject.AddComponent(meshRenderer);
}
```

The meshRenderer variable is being added to a component list in AddComponent(), but goes out of scope at the end of this function.

Later on (in the game's update/draw loops) this component is called and everything works, despite the object having gone out of scope during initialization.

Do I understand something wrong about scope, is it safe to use like this or is there another approach I should take (without having to make member variables of each of my components)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I strongly recommend using make_shared<> (shared pointer) or make_unique<>, or at least learning about them, instead of "new" and "delete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you to study C++ more before starting big projects like game engine.

What goes out of scope is the `meshRenderer` variable that is of type `MeshComponent*`, that is pointer to `MeshComponent`. What happens when pointer goes out of scope? Nothing at all. The memory was allocated on heap using the `new` operator and it will stay there until you deallocate it using `delete` operator.

Answer (score 1):

> Later on (in the game's update/draw loops) this component is called and **everything works, despite the object having gone out of scope during initialization**.

That because in the block:

```
void Initialize()
{     
   MeshComponent* meshRenderer = new MeshComponent(mesh, material);
   m_GameObject.AddComponent(meshRenderer);
}
```

The variable in the stack is the *pointer* (`meshRenderer`), the pointed object is allocated on *heap*.
So when `}` is reached only the pointer is "destroyed" but *not* the pointed object.

This is one of mainly cause of error with dynamic memory.

So it should work "correctly" *until the components manager handles correctly the dynamic memory* (e.g. proper deallocation).

---

> is it safe to use like this or is there another approach I should take (without having to make member variables of each of my components)?

Safe a relative concept. Even someone with a great experience in C or C++ dynamic memory could make some mistakes producing *memory leaks*.

I can suggest you to read and to learn [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). [*since C++11*]

A smart pointer simplify the concept of pointer because (if correctly used) it handles automatically the memory deallocation.

In your case, for example, an [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) could be useful.

A *shared pointer* allows multiple instance of pointers which refer the same object (the same memory). Indeed, several `std::shared_ptr` objects may own the same object. The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed (or the programmer explicit wants).

Comment: +1 Though I would use unique_ptr, or be strict about shared_ptr ownership and only return weak_ptr to users.  Note this isn't very popular with the purists, who see performance problems lurking behind every smart pointer.

Comment: @Robinson I perfectly agree with you. Indeed I rarely use smart pointers, but my work scenario is always about low level algorithm. In game engine instead I've see them a lots, especially in a *Component Manager System*, regard *shared pointer* is commonly used. That's why I shortly suggested that.

Answer (score 0):

> Later on (in the game's update/draw loops) this component is called and everything works, despite the object having gone out of scope during initialization.

That component doesn't go out of scope unless being `delete`d somewhere else.